# Shell script double quote (") is being ignored

Tags: shell, groovy, jenkins-groovy, truncate, double-quotes

In my Jenkinsfile. I have a command

`sh "./detect.sh --detect.project.name=\"ABC - XYZ\" --detect.timeout=18000  ... "`

In log of my Jenkins job, I see following:

`sh "./detect.sh --detect.project.name=ABC - XYZ --detect.timeout=18000  ... "`

Note: (1) The double quote in project name is removed! (2) My shell command is multi-line and if I remove the double quote, it failts with error - `expecting anything but ''\n''`

Beacuse of which the detect just takes the project name as `ABC` instead of `ABC - XYZ` and fails during execution as no such project exists.

How can I pass double quote in project name so that detect can treat the entire `ABC - XYZ` as project name?

Comment: You do not have to double quote the command following `sh`.  So just do `sh ./detect.sh ...  "ABC - XYZ" ...`

Comment: @Nic3500: My shell command is multi-line. If I remove double quote from it - I get an error `expecting anything but ''\n''`